# C# | Aumentar a janela do Console Application

Tags: c#, console

Como eu faço para Aumentar a janela do Console Application no C#?

Utilizo o Visual Studio 2017 Community.

O meu programa sera feito em Console Application, eu preciso alterar o tamanho da janela do Console que está sendo gerada.

Answer (score 4):

Voce pode alterar usando `Console.SetWindowSize`:

```
 Console.SetWindowSize(60, 100);
```

Você também pode definir somente altura `Console.WindowHeight` ou largura `Console.WindowWidth`

Atençao porque se voce  colocar um tamanho maior que o disponvível vai te lançar um exception.

Comment: Sim, também deu certo, pensei que fosse na unidade de pixel, mas vi que são medidos por posições. valeu.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar o método [Console.SetWindowSize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize(v=vs.110).aspx) da classe Console para definir as dimensões da janela.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetWindowSize(10, 5);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado meu caro.